# Recover data after multiple wipe

Tags: data-recovery

I have a company laptop where I had many of my personal files and pictures. Now, I'm leaving for a new opportunity and I need to give them back the machine. So I used DBAN to wipe the hard drive.

I'm a bit paranoid so I wiped the HDD many times with DOD then DOD short. After that Quick and DOD short again and finally PRNG method.

I installed a new copy of Windows 10 at the end.

Assuming that some colleagues don't like me too much, is there in any chance that the IT team can recover my data from that drive by some kind of software or other ways?

Answer (score 1):

It is very, very unlikely that they could recover data from the hard drive after even a single wipe.

But I would be more concerned about the data that is not on the drive, like your company cloud storage, email, backups, etc.

Comment: Cloud and email has only professional data which is available for everyone. What concern me is my personal data that was stored in the drive that I wiped.

Comment: @August - Because it was a corporate supplied laptop with presumably a corporate build, the question of what other monitoring functions were running would be the main concern. Just because you didn't overtly upload personal data doesn't mean a monitoring function didn't. When playing in other people's fish bowls, assume they have unlimited access.

Comment: @user10216038 After I was given the laptop I used DBAN to wipe the hard drive and installed a fresh copy of windows myself. And we all work with gmail services so I assume there was no spyware or other program installed. The only doubt is one day, I was on a business trip and I needed a storage device so I copied the content of my external hard drive to that pc to use the external hard drive. When back home I got my external drive clean then copied back my data from the pc. That's it!